# How to refer to ?attr/actionBarSize in resources value?

Tags: android, android-resources

I try to refer to `?attr/actionBarSize` in `dimens.xml` in two ways:

```
<dimen name="bottom_margin">?attr/actionBarSize</dimen>
<dimen name="bottom_margin">@attr/actionBarSize</dimen>
```

The first one is compiling but I get runtime error from inflanter:

```
RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {pl.example/pl.example.ui.gui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

So question is: how to refer to that value?

Next I will use this value in animator or use from code.

Comment: `<dimen name="bottom_margin">yourheight dp</dimen>` for easy output

Comment: and how you use this value next?

Answer (score -1):

Actually I don't see if there is a sense to declare own dimensions if it already declared in theme, so it would be better to use `?attr/actionBarSize` directly where you need that.

But if you really need it for some reason try as following:

```
<dimen name="bottom_margin">?actionBarSize</dimen>
```

Comment: Sorry but not work. The app is compiled but I get runtime error: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: @LunaVulpo I assume you use a theme without that attribute

Comment: I don't understend. Can u provide more ditails?

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax is:

```
?android:attr/actionBarSize
```

Answer (score -2):

Use it like this with android key.

```
android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
```

Comment: I know that I can do that but I need it for Animator xml and in other pleases. And for now is same coincidence that it has that value but in future can be changed so I want to separated it.